# Where is page table in RAM?

Tags: linux, operating-system, page-tables

I know the page table is in RAM, but where it is in RAM exactly? Will there be specific places reserved for the page table?  If no, how does the OS know where the page table is in RAM? Will the OS load the page table for a program before it runs?

Comment: Which OS are you asking about?  Different OS's could implement page tables different ways, so there is unlikely to be a universally true answer.

Comment: Refer to your processor/MMU user manual and OS documentation.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner, Linux